# Django, Deleting or resetting object but not remove from database

Tags: python, django, object, django-models, instance

I'm working with django, and I'm iterating over a list of different keys,
Now per key i want to write some things to a file, so I get the objects by key. like:

```
for ids in Idlist:

    try:
        Loci = Locus.objects.get(Gen_ID=ids)

    except:
        #no locus info found
        pass
    try:    
        Itag = Itag_annotatie.objects.get(Gen_ID=ids)
    except:
        #no Itag info found
        pass
    try:
        Ncbi = NCBI.objects.get(Gen_ID=ids)
    except:
        #No NCBI info found
        pass

    writer.writerow([Itag.Gen_ID, Itag.Solyc, Ncbi.defname, Loci.Lociname])
```

(example code)
How do I empty the object after each writerow?
every key is different.
(didn't create database with django, Implemented my own database)

So I want to empy the object Instance in Python, but NOT delete the information from the database

Henkes

edit: I want to empty the Ncbi, Loci and Itag objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set them to `None` at the beginning of for loop:

```
for ids in Idlist:
    Loci = None
    Itag = None
    Ncbi = None  

    try:
        Loci = Locus.objects.get(Gen_ID=ids)

    except:
        #no locus info found
        pass
    ....
    #your for loop 
    ....
    # use attributes if objects found, else use ''
    writer.writerow([Itag.Gen_ID if Itag else '',
                   Itag.Solyc if Itag else '', 
                   Ncbi.defname if Ncbi else '', 
                   Loci.Lociname if Loci else ''])
```

Comment: I've tried that one already, but then I get the following error:
`'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Gen_ID'`

Comment: @Henkes yes, that will happen. You need to handle `except` part appropriately for this. Or Handle empty/not found objects (which will be `None`) in `writerow` call.

Comment: Henkes, see last line of function `write` in my answer for resolve this.

Comment: I tried this, but I get some weird spaces in the lines and sometimes enters. Iḿ trying to figure out how this happens.

Comment: @Henkes, yes again that will happen because your are adding empty strings when objects are `None`.

Comment: I tried this way with 2 different Ids. so i would expect only 2 lines in my output.
But i got four lines.. with 2 of them just empty.
and those ID's shouldn't be None because those are present in the database.

Comment: Ah now it worked! 
thank you so much, the last problem was just because of my own incompetence.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, ther is a mistake about your approach,

```
try:
    Loci = Locus.objects.get(Gen_ID=ids)

except:
    #no locus info found
    pass
```

If there is no data with `Gen_ID=ids`, then your variable `Loci` will not be created (if you did not initialize it before), thus,

```
writer.writerow([Itag.Gen_ID, Itag.Solyc, NCBI.defname, Loci.Lociname])
```

will raise error since `Loci` did not created at all.

As for the answer to your question, you can set it to `None`

```
writer.writerow([Itag.Gen_ID, Itag.Solyc, NCBI.defname, Loci.Lociname])
Loci = None
Itag = None
NCBI = None
```

But setting them to `None` is a better approach if your `get` functions return no record

```
for ids in Idlist:
    try:
        Loci = Locus.objects.get(Gen_ID=ids)
    except Locus.DoesNotExist:
        #no locus info found
        Loci = None
    try:    
        Itag = Itag_annotatie.objects.get(Gen_ID=ids)
    except Itag_annotatie.DoesNotExist:
        #no Itag info found
        Itag = None
    try:
        Ncbi = NCBI.objects.get(Gen_ID=ids)
    except NCBI.DoesNotExist:
        #No NCBI info found
        Ncbi = None

    if not Loci:
        continue # end this loop without doing anything else and start the next loop 
    writer.writerow([Itag.Gen_ID if Itag else '', 
                     Itag.Solyc  if Itag else '', 
                     Ncbi.defname if Ncbi else '', 
                     Loci.Lociname # can not be `None`
                   ])
```

EDIT: Normally, `Loci,`Itag`and`NCBI`will be set to new values if your database method get a record, otherwise they will set to`None`.

EDIT 2: I hope i understood correctly. `continue` statement is used in loops and let you end current loop and start the next loop (if available).

Comment: This would be a perfect answer if you didn't perpetuate the OP's error of catching all exceptions each time, rather than the specific `DoesNotExist` - eg `except Locus.DoesNotExist`, etc.

Comment: Sometimes one "Id" will have values for Ncbi and Itag but not for Loci.
in this case nothing will be written away in the file.
But I actually want the rest to be written away. and for those values that not exist write nothing ""

Comment: @FallenAngel Almost, But: the only table that always has information is Itag. 
Locus and NCBI can be empy.

if the object is None there should be null written away.
can you help me with that?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Henkes can you explain it? What do you mean with *object is `None`* and there is a confusion about when you will write it an when you will not...

CAn you update qour question with some more explanation?

Answer (score 0):

In your place, I would have made ​​a processing code of each object in a separate function:

```
def write(ids):
    try:
        Loci = Locus.objects.get(Gen_ID=ids)
    except Locus.DoesNotExist:
        Loci = None
    try:    
        Itag = Itag_annotatie.objects.get(Gen_ID=ids)
    except Itag.DoesNotExist:
        Itag = None
    try:
        Ncbi = NCBI.objects.get(Gen_ID=ids)
    except Ncbi.DoesNotExist:
        Ncbi = None

    writer.writerow([Itag.Gen_ID if Itag else None, 
                     Itag.Solyc if Itag else None, 
                     Ncbi.defname if Ncbi else None, 
                     Loci.Lociname if Loci else None])

for ids in Idlist:
     write(ids)
```

In this case, the variables are local and they do not need to reset.

---

Another (more clean) variant:

```
for ids in Idlist:
    Locis = Locus.objects.filter(Gen_ID=ids)[:1]
    Itags = Itag_annotatie.objects.filter(Gen_ID=ids)[:1]
    Ncbis = NCBI.objects.filter(Gen_ID=ids)[:1]
    writer.writerow([Itags[0].Gen_ID if Itags else None, 
                     Itags[0].Solyc if Itags else None, 
                     Ncbis[0].defname if Ncbis else None, 
                     Locis[0].Lociname if Locis else None])
```

Queryset like `Foobar.objects.filter(Gen_ID=ids)[:1]` will return an empty list if it is not found, or a list with the first matching entry.

Comment: That will raise an error to, since if related `try` block fails, then that oject will not be created and `Item.Gen_ID if Item else None` will be raise error

Comment: also, **do not** post more than one answer, just edit your first answer to add other approaches

Comment: @FallenAngel, you are right, I just edit this answer, but I recommend you to see my more preferred answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12672869/284947

Comment: Than join this answer with other **more preferred** one

Comment: @FallenAngel, unfortunately, I can not just delete the answer. Secondly, both answers offer different way to solution, so I offered them as two different answers.

Comment: I tried this and got the following error:`Exception Type:  ValueError
Exception Value:  

invalid literal for int() with base 10: ','

Exception Location:  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py in get_prep_value, line 966`
This is a Django error somewhere.

Comment: They might be offer different approaches, but they are not **totally** different [A related topic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25209/173052). So you join them as a single answer and define that is two different approaches

Comment: As I understand it, the variable `ids` is a string with numbers separated by commas, right? If true, use `ids.split(',')` as filter arguments. It is also possible that you have not defined correctly some field in model (maybe you use `models.IntegerField` for the field, which is a string in the database)

Comment: @FallenAngel, maybe you are right, but is it possible to remove one of the answers now?

Comment: Idlist is a string with Numbers separated by commas,
I split that one by using Idlist.split(",")
then I looped over the list by using:
`for ids in Idlist:`

I don't think I messed my models up. But I will check!

Comment: @defuz you can edit one question and delete the other (or report it for deletion)